# How to maintain data integrity in Laravel Morph relationship on database layer?

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration, relationship, database-indexes

In the context of a **SaaS-based system**, I am designing a role management system using **Laravel's Morph relationship technique**. This system involves assigning roles to both company entities and admin users. I plan to implement this using a single table for roles, and I'm considering the structure of this table.

Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on how to ensure data integrity at the database level. I intend to use two columns in the roles table (if there is another best approach please suggest me):

- **roleable_id** (which could contain IDs such as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.)
- **roleable_type** (which would represent the type of entity, e.g., Company::class or Admin::class)

My primary concern is how to establish **foreign keys (FKs) & indexes** in the database that link these columns to their respective tables, ensuring that data integrity is maintained.

I often find this aspect confusing, and I would greatly appreciate assistance in understanding the best practices for implementing FKs and indexes to guarantee data integrity in this scenario

Let me give you some example,

we have these

| roleable_id | roleable_type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company::class | Role name 1 |
| 2 | Admin::class | Role name 2 |

Then  how to make sure, this combination (Company::class + 1) either points to Company Table/Model or Admin Model/Table.

I'm just curious regarding migration related stuff while adding index,Fk's

Comment: From what I know, you cannot create a foreign key for morphable columns, like the ID and the Type, because you cannot dynamically link `X` to table `Y`

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible, but you can use the event on `deleting` a certain model

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     */
    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::deleting(function (User $user) {
            // ...
        });
    }
```

alternatively you can also you can use model Observer
generate by

```
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User
```

then edit it yourself

```
class UserObserver
{

/**
     * Handle the User "deleted" event.
     */
    public function deleted(User $user): void
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

then add this to your EventServiceProvider

```
public function boot(): void
{
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

Note: When issuing a mass update or delete query via Eloquent, deleting, and deleted model events will not be dispatched for the affected models.